# How to calculate number of room based on number of person in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to calculate total number of rooms based on the total number of person enter by the user. The maximum number of person cannot exceed 7 person.  The type of room will be Twin (2 person per room-adult&child), Double (2 person per room-adult&child), Single (1 person per room) and extra bed. The type of persons will be Adult, Child with bed and child without bed.

For the room calculation, we need to add [(adult + child with bed/2)] to get the room value. By default, the system must place the number of room in twin sharing. The child with bed must be placed in twin room with adult. So, any exceeding odd number, will result in single room.

Example: 4 adult and 1 child; Total 5 person.
Result: 2 twin and 1 single room.

The user can change this result by changing the twin to double or extra bed. 
Result: 2 double and 1 extra bed. The extra bed attached to the double room.

I need some help to work this function in JavaScript. So far I managed to do the system calculation but when try to do the changes by manual it caused error in the calculation.

Example: 4 adult and 1 child; Total 5 person.
Default: 2 twin and 1 single room.
User change to 1 twin (at least 1 twin is must because there is one child), Single can be maximum 2 rooms and the balance 1 adult can select 1 extra bed.

I need some help here:

```
    function cal_rooms()
    {
        var have_extra_bed="<?=$room_have_extra_bed;?>";
        var adult = document.getElementById("adult").value;
        var childbed = document.getElementById("childbed").value;
        var childwbed = document.getElementById("childwbed").value;
        document.getElementById("doubleroom").value="0";
        //var totals1=(parseInt(adult));
        var totals=(parseInt(adult)+parseInt(childbed)+parseInt(childwbed));

        if(adult==0)
        {
            document.getElementById("childbed").disabled=true;
            document.getElementById("childwbed").disabled=true;

            document.getElementById("childbed").value="0";
            document.getElementById("childwbed").value="0";
            document.getElementById("totalperson").value="";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("childbed").disabled=false;
            document.getElementById("childwbed").disabled=false;

            if(totals>7)
            {
                var newtots=(totals-parseInt(adult));
                alert("Cannot exceed 7!");
                document.getElementById("adult").value=0;

                document.getElementById("childbed").value="0";
                document.getElementById("childwbed").value="0";
                document.getElementById("totalperson").value="";
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("totalperson").value=totals;

                ///rooms
                var numrooms=((parseInt(adult)+parseInt(childbed))/2);
                var new_numrooms=Math.ceil(numrooms);
                var check_numrooms=(parseInt(new_numrooms)-numrooms);
                var single_num=Math.ceil(check_numrooms);
                var twin_num=(parseInt(new_numrooms)-parseInt(single_num));
                var doubleroom=document.getElementById("doubleroom").value;
                var totals_room1=(parseInt(twin_num)+parseInt(doubleroom)+parseInt(single_num));

                if(have_extra_bed=="Y")
                {
                    if(parseInt(adult)>=parseInt(childbed))
                    {

                            var max_single_can_select=(parseInt(adult)-parseInt(childbed));

                            document.getElementById("twin").value=twin_num;
                            document.getElementById("single").value=single_num;
                            document.getElementById("temp_single").value=single_num;
                            document.getElementById("def_single").value=single_num;
                            document.getElementById("max_single").value=max_single_can_select;

                            document.getElementById("extrabed").value="0";
                            document.getElementById("totalroom").value=totals_room1;
                            document.getElementById("totalextra").value="0";
                            document.getElementById("single").disabled=false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            document.getElementById("twin").value=twin_num;
                            document.getElementById("extrabed").value=single_num;
                            document.getElementById("single").value="0";
                            document.getElementById("temp_single").value="0";
                            document.getElementById("def_single").value="0";
                            document.getElementById("max_single").value="0";


                            var extra_a=document.getElementById("extrabed").value;
                            var single_a=document.getElementById("single").value;
                            var twin_a=document.getElementById("twin").value
                            var doubleroom=document.getElementById("doubleroom").value;
                            var totals_room1=(parseInt(single_a)+parseInt(twin_a)+parseInt(doubleroom));

                            document.getElementById("totalroom").value=totals_room1;
                            document.getElementById("totalextra").value=extra_a;
                            document.getElementById("single").disabled=true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(parseInt(adult)>=parseInt(childbed))
                    {
                            var max_single_can_select=(parseInt(adult)-parseInt(childbed));

                            document.getElementById("twin").value=twin_num;
                            document.getElementById("single").value=single_num;
                            document.getElementById("temp_single").value=single_num;
                            document.getElementById("def_single").value=single_num;
                            document.getElementById("max_single").value=max_single_can_select;


                            document.getElementById("extrabed").value="0";
                            document.getElementById("totalroom").value=totals_room1;
                            document.getElementById("totalextra").value="0";

                            document.getElementById("single").disabled=false;
                            document.getElementById("extrabed").disabled=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById("twin").value=twin_num;
                        document.getElementById("single").value=single_num;
                        document.getElementById("temp_single").value=single_num;
                        document.getElementById("def_single").value=single_num;
                        document.getElementById("max_single").value="0";
                        document.getElementById("extrabed").value="0";
                        document.getElementById("single").disabled=true;
                        document.getElementById("extrabed").disabled=true;

                        var extra_a=document.getElementById("extrabed").value;
                        var single_a=document.getElementById("single").value;
                        var twin_a=document.getElementById("twin").value
                        var doubleroom=document.getElementById("doubleroom").value;
                        var totals_room1=(parseInt(single_a)+parseInt(twin_a)+parseInt(doubleroom));

                        document.getElementById("totalroom").value=totals_room1;
                        document.getElementById("totalextra").value=extra_a;

                    }
                }

                return surcharge();
            }
        }
    }

function cal_single()
    {
    ///Start single function

        var choose_single = document.getElementById("single").value;
        var single_pick = document.getElementById("single_pick").value;
        var extra_pick = document.getElementById("extra_pick").value;

        var checked_for_doubleroom = document.getElementById("temp_double").value;
        var checked_for_single = document.getElementById("temp_single").value;
        var checked_for_def_single = document.getElementById("def_single").value;

        var total_pax_adult = document.getElementById("adult").value;
        var total_pax_childbed = document.getElementById("childbed").value;
        var total_pax_bed = (parseInt(total_pax_adult)+parseInt(total_pax_childbed));


                if (parseInt(total_pax_bed)%2 == 0)
                {
                    ////Even Number

                    //document.getElementById("temp_single").value=choose_single;
                    var temp_twin = document.getElementById("twin").value;
                    var temp_double = document.getElementById("temp_double").value;
                    var temp_single = document.getElementById("temp_single").value;
                    var temp_extra = document.getElementById("temp_extra").value;
                    var total_temp = ((parseInt(temp_twin)*2)+(parseInt(temp_double)*2)+parseInt(temp_single)+parseInt(temp_extra));
                    var new_total_temp = ((parseInt(temp_twin)*2)+(parseInt(temp_double)*2)+parseInt(choose_single)+parseInt(temp_extra));

                    if(total_temp>total_pax_bed)
                    {
                        alert("Total Number of Room Exceed Total number of Pax!");
                        document.getElementById("single").value=temp_single;
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                            var def_single=document.getElementById("def_single").value;
                        var doubleroom=document.getElementById("doubleroom").value;
                        var single=document.getElementById("single").value;

                        var adult = document.getElementById("adult").value;
                        var childbed = document.getElementById("childbed").value;

                        ///rooms
                        var numrooms=((parseInt(adult)+parseInt(childbed))/2);
                        var new_numrooms=Math.ceil(numrooms);
                        var check_numrooms=(parseInt(new_numrooms)-numrooms);
                        var single_num=Math.ceil(check_numrooms);
                        var twin_num=(parseInt(new_numrooms)-parseInt(single_num));

                        var max_sing=document.getElementById("max_single").value;

                        if(single>max_sing)
                        {
                            if(max_sing==0)
                            {
                                alert("Single cannot been select");
                                document.getElementById("single").value=def_single;
                                return false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert("Single cannot exceed "+max_sing);
                                document.getElementById("single").value=def_single;
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(single==0)
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var latest_twin_num=(parseInt(twin_num)-parseInt(single));
                                var min_twin_sh=childbed;

                                if(parseInt(latest_twin_num)<=parseInt(min_twin_sh))
                                {
                                    var new_latest_twin=min_twin_sh;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    var new_latest_twin=latest_twin_num;
                                }

                                    document.getElementById("single").value=single;
                                    document.getElementById("twin").value=new_latest_twin;
                                    document.getElementById("max_single").value=new_latest_twin;
                                    document.getElementById("temp_single").value=single;
                                    document.getElementById("single_pick").value="Y";

                                        var extra_a=document.getElementById("extrabed").value;
                                        var single_a=document.getElementById("single").value;
                                        var twin_a=document.getElementById("twin").value
                                        var doubleroom=document.getElementById("doubleroom").value;
                                        var totals_room1=(parseInt(single_a)+parseInt(twin_a)+parseInt(doubleroom));

                                        document.getElementById("totalroom").value=totals_room1;
                                        document.getElementById("totalextra").value=extra_a;

                            }
                        }


                        document.getElementById("single").disabled=true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
```

Comment: If you post what you have so far, it'll help us understand the question and requirements better.

Comment: Post your javascript code

Comment: The JavaScript code is quit long. Sorry. There are so many probability that need to be included. Sorry. Hope this can help u to understand.  @Helpful

Answer (score 0):

try using javsacript function modulus `x= y%2` this will give you exact rooms required and if there's a remainder you can add one more room to it.

Comment: I used the modulus but still not working as it should.

Comment: One thing i would like to understand regarding issue? if there are 4 adults and 1 child, user selects 1 twin - it acomodates 1 adult + 1 child, correct? and then for rest 3 persons they can select double bed room occupies 2 and for remaining person will it be having extra bed or additional single room?

Comment: Yes. You are right. The system must have min 1 twin or double room to accommodate the child. The current coding only check the twin sharing for the confirmation. But when user select the double room which is the exchange option (the double room actually conversion of twin room) meaning whatever number in twin room can change it to double. I don't know how to put it in coding to make it work. What I want is when the user select single room, the system must check both twin room and double to check the min requirement for the child. Only the remaining of adult can select single.

Comment: So in that case you check minimum required rooms based on persons total 5 persons - minimum 2 rooms required (twin or double) and if additional person can accommodate by having 1 more extra bed. you check `y = x%2` it will give you remainder persons if it's 0 then minimum room will be `z = x/2` else  it's `z = x/2 + 1` (add +1 to minimum room required).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I manage to find some alternative solution. I plan to do the double room request separately. If user plan for single room or extra bed, then they need to select it first. Then finally, can request for double room which will minus from twin and won't interfere with any other number.  Meaning, the double room won't involve in the calculation. If they select the double room first, then they cannot add single or extra bed. Either way the minimum requirement for the child are guaranteed.